# Android changing XML layout Changes data fields

Tags: java, android, xml

Here's a head scratcher...(at least for me)
I have a contact list that displays a list of contacts from my Db. When a user clicks on one of the contacts an edit activity comes up. It all works perfectly as laid out currently, but I need to have the edit activity display the last name entry before the first name. Thinking that all the fields should have a one to one relationship, I went ahead and moved the editText(XML) for the last name above the first name in the edit activity thinking that this should be referenced by the id of the EditText. After doing so, the program is now displaying the first name in the last name field and vise-versa. I have tried wiping the user data on the emulator with no difference. I already realize this is probably one of those UH-DUH! type questions, but if anyone can point out the obvious for me, it would be appreciated. All the code shown is in the now-working state:

I've removed some chunks that would have nothing to do with my issue.
Thanks to anyone having a look at this for me! 
Ken

XML:

```
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_edit_first_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:hint="@string/contact_edit_first_name"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:background="@color/warn" >
    </EditText>
     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_edit_last_name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:hint="@string/contact_edit_last_name"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:background="@color/warn" >
    </EditText>
```

This is the contact activity that displays the listView rows, and calls
createContact which sends an intent to add, edit or delete rows.

```
    public class ContactsActivity extends ListActivity implements
    LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {

  private SimpleCursorAdapter adapter; 

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
          @Override
  public void onCreate //DO THE ON CREATE STUFF -removed

    fillData();
    registerForContextMenu(getListView());

    Button add_contact = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add_contact_button);

    add_contact.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            createContact();
        }
      });
   }

  // Create the options menu to INSERT from the XML file
  // removed - not relevant
  // return true for the menu to be displayed
  }

  // When the insert menu item is selected, call CreateContact
  //Removed
      createContact();
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }

  private void createContact() {
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ContactEditActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
      }

   //The onListItemClick sends a URI which flags the contactEditActivity
   //that this is an edit rather than a new insert.


  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
   super.onResume();
   //Starts a new or restarts an existing Loader in this manager
   getLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, null, this);
  }

   //The fillData method binds the simpleCursorAadapter to the listView.
  private void fillData() {

    //The desired columns to be bound:
    String[] from = new String[] { ContactsDB.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, ContactsDB.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME };

    //The XML views that the data will be bound to:
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.label2, R.id.label};
    // The creation of a loader using the initLoader method call.

    getLoaderManager().initLoader(0, null, this);
    adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.contact_row, null, from,
        to, 0);
    setListAdapter(adapter);
  }
  // Sort the names by last name, then by first name
  String orderBy = ContactsDB.COLUMN_LAST_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC"
  + "," + ContactsDB.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC" ;

  // Creates a new loader after the initLoader () call
  @Override
  public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
//ETC
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {
    adapter.swapCursor(data); //Call requires Min API 11
  }

  @Override
  public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
    // swap the cursor adapter

}
```

And Finally, this is the contact edit code that is likely the source of my grief...maybe not. Could be the save state doesn't map to the id's?

```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_edit);

    Log.i(TAG, "INSIDE ONCREATE");

    mCategory = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.category);
    mLastName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_last_name);
    mFirstName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_first_name);
    mHomePhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_home_phone);
    mCellPhone = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_cell_phone);
//****************ECT. ETC.

   //DECLARE THE BUTTONS AND SET THE DELETE ENABLED FALSE - REMOVED - NOT PERTINANT
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    // Check if the URI is from a new instance or a saved record
    }

    // Set the save button to check the required fields, save the contact and finish
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      public void onClick(View view) {
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mLastName.getText().toString()) ||
                TextUtils.isEmpty(mFirstName.getText().toString())) {
          makeToast();
        } else {
          setResult(RESULT_OK);
          finish();
        }
      }
    });

    // Set the delete button to delete the contact and finish - REMOVED - NOT PERTINANT

  private void fillData(Uri uri) {

    // QUERY PARAMETER projection - A list of which columns to return.
    // Passing null will return all columns, which is inefficient (but used now!)
    // null, null and null are: selection, selection args, and sort order for specific items

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null); 

    if (cursor != null) {
      cursor.moveToFirst();
      String category = cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.COLUMN_CATEGORY));
      for (int i = 0; i < mCategory.getCount(); i++) {
          String s = (String) mCategory.getItemAtPosition(i);
          Log.i("CATEGORY", s); ////////////////////////////////////////////
        if (s.equalsIgnoreCase(category)) {
          mCategory.setSelection(i);
        }
      };

      mLastName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
          .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.COLUMN_LAST_NAME)));
      mFirstName.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME)));
      mHomePhone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER)));
      mCellPhone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.COLUMN_CELL_NUMBER)));
      mWorkPhone.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
              .getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsDB.COLUMN_WORK_NUMBER)));
      mFax.setText(cursor.getString(cursor
//****************ECT. ETC.  
      //close the cursor
    }
  }

  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    saveState();
    outState.putParcelable(whateverContentProvider.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, contactUri);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    saveState();
  }
  private void saveState() {
    String category = (String) mCategory.getSelectedItem();
    String someLAST = mLastName.getText().toString().valueOf(findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_last_name));
    String lastName = mLastName.getText().toString();
    String firstName = mFirstName.getText().toString();
    String someFIRST = mFirstName.getText().toString().valueOf(findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_first_name));
    String homePhone = mHomePhone.getText().toString();
    String somePhone = mHomePhone.getText().toString().valueOf(findViewById(R.id.contact_edit_home_phone));
    String cellPhone = mCellPhone.getText().toString();
    String workPhone = mWorkPhone.getText().toString();
//****************ECT. ETC.
    //Some logging I used to show that the first name field still came up first
    //after changing the order of the editTexts.
    Log.i("LAST NAME", lastName);
    Log.i("SOME LAST", someLAST);
    Log.i("FIRST NAME", firstName);
    Log.i("SOME FIRST", someFIRST);
    Log.i("Home Phone", homePhone);
    Log.i("SOME PHONE", somePhone);


    // Save if first name and last name are entered
    // The program will save only last name when a user presses back button with text in last name

    if (lastName.length() == 0 || firstName.length() == 0) {
      return;
    }
    // ContentValues class is used to store a set of values that the contentResolver can process.
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(ContactsDB.COLUMN_CATEGORY, category);
    values.put(ContactsDB.COLUMN_LAST_NAME, lastName);//ANNIE
    values.put(ContactsDB.COLUMN_FIRST_NAME, firstName);
    values.put(ContactsDB.COLUMN_PHONE_NUMBER, homePhone); 
//****************ECT. ETC.

    if (contactUri == null) {
      // Create a new contact
      contactUri = getContentResolver().insert(whateverContentProvider.CONTENT_URI, values);
    } else {
      // Update an existing contact
      getContentResolver().update(contactUri, values, null, null);
    }
  }
//MAKE A TOAST DOWN HERE - REMOVED - NOT PERTINANT
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried cleaning the project (regenerating de R).
Also, try restarting your IDE.

This may seem stupid but actually can solve the issue...

Comment: Thanks to both of you for the quick input!

Answer (score 2):

try cleaning your project.  Weird things happen sometimes within Eclipse.

Comment: Yes...That did it. Thanks to both of you for the suggestion. I told you it was an UH-DUH question :-) Should've thought of that 4 hours ago!!